# Identifying the diameter of reinforced steel bars in a column design schematic

Tags: civil-engineering, structural-engineering

I'm having trouble identifying the diameter of the reinforced steel bars in the structural steel design for a slab and a beam of a building complex. You can see it 
[here (PDF)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xszs9wurf8gmk65/POS%20300%2C400%2C500%2C600%2C700%2C800%20%281%29.pdf?dl=0).

I'm told there's column design in this file, but I only see beam design. Is the diameter number of the steel before or after the diameter sign? Why are there numbers like 12/20 after the diameter sign? Is there any column design here at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column design schematics are "POS S1" and "POS S2", on the bottom center-right of the page.

The nomenclature here has some peculiarities I'm unsure about, so someone else might come up with a better answer, but here goes... You'll see that there are basically two ways to describe the rebar:

- Longitudinal bars tend to be in the form "➀ $4\ \phi 16\ l=391\ (2)$": This translates to 4 rebars identified by ➀ elsewhere which have a 16 mm diameter and are each 391 cm long. I'm not sure what the (2) means.
- Transversal bars are described similarly (when their dimensions are shown), but they are then often repeated in this drawing in a manner I don't quite understand: "➄ $18\ \phi 8/10/20$". I don't understand what the $/10/20$ is supposed to mean. That being said, when their positions along the column are shown as ➄ $14\ \phi 8/20$, that just means that there are 14 cages made of 8 mm rebar distributed with a 20-cm spacing.